# what is the reason for Jersy RESTFUL web service output in XML format

Tags: java, web-services

Hi I am new to Jersy restful web service. I simply created one restful web service with pojo class. I did not mention where ever in my code for xml format but I got output as xml format in browsr.

Please HELP ME reason of output showing XML format... I give my code below.

Class Order:

```
package shopping.cart.om;

public class Order 
{




       public Map<String, Order> getModel(){
              return contentProvider;
       }           
}
```

Class OrdersService:
    package shopping.cart.service;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import shopping.cart.dao.OrderDao;
import shopping.cart.om.Order;


         }
}




<id>1</id>
</order>
</orders>
```

Comment: I found this other answer useful to help answer you question as well: [beyond-the-produces-annotation-how-does-jersey-jax-rs-know-to-treat-a-pojo-a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744972/beyond-the-produces-annotation-how-does-jersey-jax-rs-know-to-treat-a-pojo-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that XML is the default format of the output, most likely. Check this question: [How to set to default to json instead of xml in jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649259/how-to-set-to-default-to-json-instead-of-xml-in-jersey)

Comment: Thanks jakop. i referred u given link question after that i changed the return output format to @Produces( { "application/json" }) but still i got same xml format output.. is this format (application/json) also return xml type output

Answer (score 0):

The question is what type of data you expect after hitting restful endpoint , if XML then you have to tell it in method level , f JSON or other you can also define this in your method , example

```
package com.hello.demo;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello  {
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String consumeTest (String requestMessage) {
  return requestMessage;
} 
}
```

Suppose you want simple text as output then

use :

```
 @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

in method level .

For detail please visit : [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html)

Apart from it if you are interested about different media type supported by jersey you may visit : [media types](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html)